# Сцепление массивов через перегрузку операций, в выводе выдает мусор. Последний пункт в main. В чем ошибка?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class TMyClass
{
    int n;
    float*mass;
public:
    TMyClass(int nn = 3, float massmass = 5);
    TMyClass(TMyClass&obj);
    ~TMyClass();

    void input();
    void output();

    TMyClass& operator=(TMyClass&v);
    int operator==(TMyClass&v);
    int operator!=(TMyClass&v);


    //friend 
    TMyClass& operator+=(int x);
    friend TMyClass operator+(TMyClass & v1, TMyClass & v2);
};

TMyClass& TMyClass::operator=(TMyClass&v)
{
    //delete[]mass;
    n = v.n;
    mass = new float[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mass[i] = v.mass[i];
    return *this;

}

int TMyClass::operator==(TMyClass &obj)
{
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (mass[i] == obj.mass[i]) f = 1;
        else f = 0;
    }
    return f;
}

int TMyClass::operator!=(TMyClass &obj)
{
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (mass[i] != obj.mass[i]) f = 1;
        else f = 0;
    }
    return f;

}
TMyClass& TMyClass::operator+=(int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
        mass[i] += x;

    return *this;
}

TMyClass operator+(TMyClass & v1, TMyClass & v2)
{
    int x;
    x = v1.n + v2.n;

    float *c = new float[x];
    for (int i = 0; i<v1.n; i++)
    {
        c[i] = v1.mass[i];
    }
    for (int i = v1.n; i<x; i++)
    {
        c[i] = v2.mass[i - v1.n];
    }
    TMyClass tmp(x);
    for
        (int i = 0; tmp.mass[i] = c[i]; i++)


        return tmp;



}







TMyClass::TMyClass(int nn, float massmass)
{
    n = nn;
    mass = new float;
    *mass = massmass;
}

TMyClass::TMyClass(TMyClass&obj)
{
    n = obj.n;
    mass = new float[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mass[i] = obj.mass[i];
    }
}


TMyClass::~TMyClass()
{
    delete mass;

}

void TMyClass::input()
{
    cout << "Введите количество элементов дин.массива" << endl;
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    delete[]mass;
    mass = new float[n];
    cout << "Введите эелементы массива" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "mass[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> mass[i];

    }
}

void TMyClass::output()
{
    cout << "Дин.массив mass[" << n << "]" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << mass[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    TMyClass a, b;

    a.input();
    cout << "Объект а" << endl;
    a.output();


    cout << "Объект b равный a" << endl;
    (b = a).output();
    b.output();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Cравниваем объекты a и b" << endl;
    if (a == b)cout << "Равны" << endl;
    else cout << "Неравны" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Cравниваем объекты a и b" << endl;
    if (a != b)cout << "Неравны" << endl;
    else cout << "Равны" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Прибавляем 10 к объекту a" << endl;
    (a += 10).output();
    a.output();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Суммируем два массива" << endl;
    (a + b).output();
    cout << endl;



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В вашем операторе + создаётся массив tmp, насколько я понял, вы в него хотели скопировать все значения, однако при первой же итерации в цикле вызывается return и в итоге вам вернётся неинициализированный массив, а в целом - в программе очень много утечек памяти.

Comment: а если в копирующем конструкторе и  в операторе присвоения модифицировать копируемый обьект(поскольку у вас неконстантные ссыльки), то  ваш код будет похож на Аманду Байнс  в 2013 году...

Answer (score 0):

Бессмысленный цикл

```
for (int i = 0; tmp.mass[i] = c[i]; i++)
  return tmp;
```

И заголовок бессмыслен (с чего это вдруг `tmp.mass[i] = c[i]` попало в условие цикла?), и тело цикла бессмысленно (почему-то состоит из `return`?). Т.е. на первой же итерации, если она вообще состоится, произойдет внезапный выход из функции.

Причем в остальном коде, несмотря на массу других недостатков, именно такой белиберды не наблюдается. Разные люди писали?